# Ionic/Angular: Using the Master detail pattern, the details page isn't showing up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My app uses tabs, a side menu, and the master details pattern. But, for some reason, when I try to navigate to the details page of an item in the list, nothing comes up. I'm not sure if I have the routing wrong or something.

If someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it! This is driving me crazy!

Thanks!

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      controller: 'TabsCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.feed', {
      url: '/feed',
      views: {
        'tab-feed': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-feed.html',
          controller: 'FeedCtrl'
        }
      }
    })  

    .state('event-detail', {
      url: '/event-detail/:name',
      templateUrl: 'templates/event-detail.html',
      controller: 'EventDetailCtrl'
    })
```

**tab-feed.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Feed" class="tab-feed">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button icon ion-funnel" ng-click="modal2.show()">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>  
  <ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
  </label>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="event in events | orderBy:'name' | searchEvents:search" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/event-detail/{{event.name}}">
          <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
          <h2>{{event.name}}</h2>
          <p><i class="ion-clock"></i> {{event.date | date: 'MM/dd/yy'}} | {{event.time | date: 'shortTime'}}</p>
          <p><i class="ion-location"></i> {{event.location}}</p>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
      <div class="title" ng-click="modal.show()">Add Event</div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

**EventDetailsController**

```
.controller('EventDetailCtrl', ['getLocalStorage', function($scope, getLocalStorage, $stateParams, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

  $scope.openMenu = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };    

  var name = $stateParams.name;
  $scope.event = getLocalStorage.getEvent(name);
}])
```

**getLocalStorage Service**

```
.factory('getLocalStorage', function () {

    var eventList = [];

    return {
            list: eventList,

        updateEvents: function (eventsArr) {
            if (window.localStorage && eventsArr) {
                localStorage.setItem("events", angular.toJson(eventsArr));
            }
            //update the cached version
            eventList = eventsArr;
        },

        getEvents: function () {
            eventList = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem("events") );
            return eventList ? eventList : [];
        },

        getEvent: function(name){
            for(i=0;i<eventList.length;i++){
                if(eventList[i].name == name){
                    return eventList[i];
                }
            }
          }
    };
})
```

Comment: Use Chrome to inspect, and send the errors? This will likely lead to the error that will help us determine the root cause. Is your factory initialized before being passed into the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

1) Add `abstract: true` to your `tabs` state:

```
.state('tabs', {
    url: '/tab',
    controller: 'TabsCtrl',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})
```

2) In your `EventDetailsCtrl`, if you're thinking of minification, add all your injection parameters, in order, before `function...` like this:

```
.controller('EventDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'getLocalStorage', '$stateParams', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', function($scope, getLocalStorage, $stateParams, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
```

If the above doesn't help, please post your `tabs.html` code.

Comment: It seems to be working now! Adding abstract: true to tabs made everything disappear for some reason...But, your second suggestion seemed to get everything working though!